# Spatial Autocorrelation with a low number input feature

Tags: spatial-statistics, autocorrelation, archaeology

I am an archaeologist using ArcGIS to run spatial statistics/analyses on my data. I want to study the spatial autocorrelation of artifact categories found within house structures across an archaeological site. I only have 18 features (house structures) and the statistic needs 30 features in the Input Feature Class field to yield reliable results.

Does anyone know of another statistical tool that I could use to run the analysis on a data set with a low number of features, or a way I could still use spatial autocorrelation with 18 features?

I am not very statistically savvy, so increasingly technical models would be difficult to apply.

The features are classified as polygons, there is only 18 in total, the data set 
has 338 observations.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Desktop or Online?

Comment: You are probably our of luck.  The requirement for 30 features likely means the statistic would be pretty sketchy using half that.  Are the 18 houses the only houses or the only houses where artifacts are found?  Are there another dozen or so houses with no artifacts you could include?